# Inverse transform an image from Polar to Cartesian in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to transform an image from polar to cartesian coordinates.
The image looks like this:
[Image in polar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qibfy.png)

The shape of the transformed image should be like this:
[Image in cartesian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpgHJ.jpg)

When I use OpenCV's warpPolar, I don't know where to specify the origin of the image in polar coordinates. It seems that OpenCV assumes that the origin of the polar image is at top-left (0,0), whereas in this case I would like the polar image to be centered at the bottom-middle (rows, cols/2) of the image.

```
img = cv.imread(image_path)
(rows,cols,_) = img.shape
dst = cv.warpPolar(img, (rows, cols), (rows/2, cols/2), 800, flags=(cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP))
```

After running this code, I get a strange looking [transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7xPy.jpg)

Also, I would like that the image does not completely warp since the final image should be only a segment of a circle, not a complete circle.

How can I transform the image as desired?

Comment: You can use Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick. ImageMagick allows you to specify the center. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polar and https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#depolar. Also in Wand see distortion methods at http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.1/wand/image.html.

Comment: P.S. The center can be specified in OpenCV. See https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#linearpolar

Comment: @fmw42 I have specified the center at different points, but still I get a transform similar to the one I've shown. The space between the yellow lines should be opening up, but here we see that the yellow lines are close together and forming a circular shape.

Comment: @fmw42 ImageMagick Arc Distortion did the job. Thank you!